# How do I assert that a method is called only once?

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks, mspec, fakeiteasy

```
[Subject(typeof(OnceADayProcessor))]
public class When_processing_process_twice
{
    private static ICanBeProcessedOnceADay ProcessedOnceADay;

    private Establish context = () => { OnceADayProcessor.Now = () => new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); };

    private Because of = () =>
                             {
                                 ProcessedOnceADay = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICanBeProcessedOnceADay>();
                                 ProcessedOnceADay.Process();
                                 ProcessedOnceADay.Process();
                             };

    private It should_execute = () => ProcessedOnceADay.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Expect(p => p.Process()));
    private It should_execute_only_once = () => ProcessedOnceADay.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.Expect(p => p.Process()));
}
```

edited solution:

```
[Subject(typeof(OnceADayProcessor))]
public class When_processing_a_process_twice_at_the_same_day
{
    static ICanBeProcessedOnceADay canBeProcessedOnceADay;

    Establish context = () =>
    {
        canBeProcessedOnceADay = A.Fake<ICanBeProcessedOnceADay>();
    };

    Because of = () =>
    {
        OnceADayProcessor.Process(canBeProcessedOnceADay);
        OnceADayProcessor.Process(canBeProcessedOnceADay);
    };

    It should_execute_only_once = () => 
        A.CallTo(() => canBeProcessedOnceADay.Process()).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICanBeProcessedOnceADay>();
mock.Expect(a => a.Process()).Repeat.Times(1);
...
mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Comment: This will validate only that the method is called _at least_ once, but not _exactly_ once.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace the calls to `stub.Expect()` and `stub.VerifyAllExpectations()` with `stub.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Process(), o => o.Repeat.Once())` in the `It`. If you have more than one expectation against the stub you can then put each assertion in one `It` and have them fail (or succeed) independently of each other.

The creation of the stub would go into `Establish` (essentially, creation of any dependencies and the System Under Test is part of the "arrange" phase in unit testing).

Also consider not to use `GenerateMock` but `GenerateStub` as mocks will likely lead to brittle tests when you call other methods than the ones specified with `Expect`. Libraries like FakeItEasy generally provide better and more discoverable APIs, are easier to learn and will make you fall into the "pit of success".

Comment: I dont understand why I should use a stub instead of mock. I thought I would need a mock, because I assert a call and no state.

Comment: http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#Thedifferencebetweenstubsandmocks
Mocks will break tests, stubs don't. It's as easy as that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that a method is called *only* once, you need a strict mock:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IShouldOnlyBeCalledOnce>();
mock.Expect(a => a.Process()).Repeat.Once();

sut.Process(mock)

mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

If you just use GenerateMock, it will perform an "at least" check. This also goes for Repeats.Times(x) too.